# I need the proper formatting for a regex find for this -aword-

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex, vb.net

This is my first time writing code, so give me a break. It is a project I conceived of, I am doing for humanity. And could use a little help! It will assemble clips, combine clips into videos, with over 50,000 images synchronized with audio, using pictographs I have created, that is based upon neuro science. I have all the pieces to do it, I will just need some help putting the pieces together.

I have tried to find the formatting and have used `.\w. (^-)\w(-$)` and `(^-)(a-z)(-$)` it would only find `-I-`. The project will be done in VB.net, so the formatting will have to match the Regex engine used in VB.net.

I am searching for matches in a text file, formatted like this, which will be used in several processes, just to let you know.

```
-We-  
-have--not--realized-  
-because--aspects--humanity-  
-perceive--through-  
-context--disconnectedness-  
-their--perceptions-  
-are--very--similar-  
-so--they--believe-  
-they--are--based--upon--reality-
```

And using a switch which holds the proper formatting. I looked in Rexegg.com and google searches with no luck. Can someone help me out with this? Thanks in advance!

The switch will match the text in one file against the text in another text file.

```
switch -regex ($message)
    {
        '\-\w\-\' {
         }
         '\-\w\--\w\-\' {
          }
        '\-\w\--\w\--\w\-\' {
          }
           '\-\w\--\w\--\w--\w\-\' {
          }
        '\-\w\--\w\--\w\--\w\--\w\-\' {
          }
    }
```

UPDATE:  I had worked 14 hours on the project, no wonder I missed it. `(^-).*(-$)`

I used `()` and `*?` to combine, that is what I found. If that is wrong could someone help me please?

```
switch -regex ($message)
    {
        (^-).*(-$){
         }
         '((^-).*(-$))*?((^-).*(-$))' {
          }
        '((^-).*(-$))*?((^-).*(-$))*?((^-).*(-$))' {
          }
           '((^-).*(-$))*?((^-).*(-$))*?((^-).*(-$))*? ((^-).*(-$))' {
          }
        '((^-).*(-$))*? ((^-).*(-$))*? ((^-).*(-$))*? ((^-).*(-$))*? ((^-).*(-$))' {
          }
    }
```

Comment: I had worked 14 hours on the project, no wonder I missed it. (^-).*(-$)

Comment: Just add a quantifier: `(-\w+-)+`. How is this related to Notepad++?

Comment: And by removing the + it captures each part, thanks so much.

Comment: how do  I give you credit for answering it?

Comment: I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\w` matches a single word character (i.e. `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, if you want to match more than 1 character, you have to add a quantifier `+` means 1 or more. Then your regex becomes:

`-\w+-` that means an hyphen, 1 or more word characters, an hyphen.